# Can i index an array both with a key value and an ordered numerical index?

Tags: hashmap, hashtable, unordered-map

Is there an abstract data type that preserves the order of the accessed elements but at the same time there is also a key-value based index? I.e: 
A[k1:v1, k2:v2,k3:v3]

I need a functionality that allows me to access A in both ways:

1) By its order: A[2]=v2
2) By key A[k3]=v3

Comment: If you require O(1) lookup by key and by index, then not really. But you could have a parallel hash table with numerical keys generated from a counter and procedurally attach references to the corresponding keys in the opposing table to each value...I guess.

Comment: If the indices aren't / don't get too sparse, you can simply have an array of keys alongside your hash table: to index numerically look first in the array for the key in the hash table.  If the indices will end up sparse, use a second hash table as CH Buckingham suggests.  If you use C++, you could use [`boost::multiindex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html), which wraps this kind of approach up in a clean interface.